# PrimeFaces Gmap not rendering in ui : include tag

Tags: ajax, google-maps, layout, primefaces, render

I have a problem with showing a Primeface p:gmap inside a ui:include component put in a layout page. I'm using the last version of primeface, mojarra and Tomcat 8.

this is my layout component where i try to render my google map:

```
<p:layoutUnit id="main_content" position="center" >
        <ui:include src="#{pageManagingBean.page}.xhtml" /> 
    </p:layoutUnit>
```

in the same page i have a button, when i click this:

```
    <p:menuitem value="Display referencies Map" actionListener="#{pageManagingBean.setPage('gmapdata')}" icon="ui-icon-disk" update=":main_content" ajax="true"/>
```

the value of pageManagingBean.page change in the page with the p:gmap, and without reload the entire page, ui:include should load the gmap in the center layout, this is the gmapdata.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">


    <h:head>
        <title>Google Map Displayed</title>
         <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    </h:head>    
    <h:body>


        <h1>Google Map</h1>

        <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <p:gmap center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="HYBRID" style="width:100%;height:100%" widgetVar="gmap"  />
    </f:view>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

When I click the menu item, the center layout show nothing, but if I change the `p:menuitem  ajax="true"` in `ajax="false"` all work fine and gmap is showed in the correct position, so why gmap don't render in ajax but work fine without?

**EDIT**

This problem is not only the rendering of the page gmap but also of the other pages that I try to load ajax in that part of the layout , for example, I have a page with a table of the work that should appear with the same mechanism , but   show only if I impose `ajax = false` and the subsequent update of the entire page.

**UPDATE**

I did several tests and thus constituting the page with gmap ,

```
<h:head>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
              type="text/javascript"></script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>



        <f:view contentType="text/html">
            <h1>Google Map</h1>
            <p:gmap center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="HYBIRD"
                    style="width:600px;height:400px" />
        </f:view>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

and including `ui:include` into a `<h:form id="main_content">` tag, who will update thanks to the `p:menuItem...update="main_content"`
content in the  tag is added to the page with the `ui : include` , but is not rendered map , however if I enter manually , along with `ui : include` , the tag `<gmap>` in my mainpage: at first opening the map is rendered (map in the tag gmap than i have hadded manually), but when the layout is updated in ajax through the usual function by `<p:menuItem>` , both maps ( gmap added manually and that loaded by `ui : include` ) disappear.
obviously everything works setting ajax = false .
I can not explain the problem

Comment: if i change my style with `"display:none"` with `ajax=true`, the page is added in the layout and show the `<herad>` content of `gmapdata.xhtml`, but gmap still not rendered

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it could be related to the place of the google maps script

I am not in the same situation, I have a template using ui:inser ui:composition, ui:define, ui:include...

My template:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <ui:insert name="resources">
        <ui:include src="/template/resources.xhtml"/>
    </ui:insert>

    <title>MyApp</title> 

    <ui:insert name="scripts"/>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="resources/img/favicon.png"/>
</h:head> 

<h:body>

    <f:view contentType="text/html">

        <ui:insert name="header">
            <ui:include src="/template/header.xhtml"/>
        </ui:insert>

        <ui:insert name="menu">
            <ui:include src="/template/menu.xhtml"/>
        </ui:insert>

        <ui:insert name="content"/>

        <ui:insert name="footer">
            <ui:include src="/template/footer.xhtml"/>
        </ui:insert>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and when I build the page with g:map I do

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
            template="/template/template.xhtml"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="scripts">
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"/>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <p:gmap center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="HYBRID" style="width:100%;height:100%" widgetVar="gmap"/>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

because the scripts has to be loaded in the head

And when you update main_content using ajax, what going on in the head?

I think you have to put the script in the head, form the beginig, so that the page is load with the script anyway.

EDIT

And you could have problem if you are using forward based navigation because primefaces don't support that

http://primefaces.org/faq.html

you have to concat view id with "?faces-redirect=true" in action attribute of commandLink or commandButton

UPDATE

Generally there is a Javascript function to initialize the map
This function (Generally  called initialize()) is call on the load event of the page

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

when you do an ajax request you should call this function to initialize the map

---

I try to execute your code but I have a jquery error: "TypeError: b is undefined" jquery.js.xhtml:1:30
It's seems that it is a javascript problem, I don't know how to solve it

Comment: where i have the layout and the ui:include i've put `<h:head> <script src="maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"; type="text/javascript" ></script> </h:head>` so i always have this script in my page

Comment: Ok I didn't see your comment on your question, you have several problems in many pages it could be a navigation problem, I edit my post

Comment: yes becouse it's not a navigation case... Have you error in the JavaSript console?

Comment: how can i use this with my `ActionListener="#{pageManagingBean.setPage('gmapdata')}"` , if i append "?faces-redirect=true" it doesn't work, i think the problemi isn't the redirecting because mi action listener don't change directly the url page, but change the page than the `UI:include` see and load in the layout

Comment: and in the JavaScript console? (press F12 in chrome or firefox)

Comment: java console report: `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=5.0:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'debug' of undefined`

Comment: pleas see the UPDATE in the main answer

Answer (score 0):

Update form tag: `<h:form prependId="false" id="main_content">`. In my case it is worked when i kept prependId="false".